# TPM specification physical presence requirements

Tags: trusted-platform-module

I am looking at [TPM Main-Part 1 Design Principles_v1.2_rev116_01032011](https://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/files/static_page_files/72C26AB5-1A4B-B294-D002BC0B8C062FF6/TPM%20Main-Part%201%20Design%20Principles_v1.2_rev116_01032011.pdf) and on page 69 of pdf, equivalent to page 57 of the document itself,there is comment on physical presence as follows: "Observe, the reverse logic surrounding the use of TSC_PhysicalPresence command. When the physicalPresenceCMDEnable flag is set and the physicalPresenceLock flag is not set, the TSC_PhysicalPresence command may set physicalPresenceV." This is in relation the the following diagram: [image: Physical Presence Control Logic]
I do not see any reference to physicalPresenceLock in the diagram. I want to validate that they are talking about physicalPresenceCMDEnableV flag. That is the only flag in the diagram relevant to TSC_PhysicalPresence() which is not set. Am I reading this right? Is this a typo?